# Load balance Postfix within AWS without SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, postfix-mta

I'm working on a project for a client who does message pre and post-processing at very high volumes. I'm trying to figure out a reliable configuration between two or three API servers that will push outgoing email messages to any of two or more instances of Postfix. This is for outbound only and it's preferred not to have a single point of failure.

I am a bit lost within the AWS ecosystem and all I know is we cannot use SES and the client is set up for high volume smtp with Amazon, so throttling is not an issue.

I've looked into ELB, HAProxy, and a few other things but the whole thing has now gotten muddy and I'm not sure if I'm just overthinking it now.

Any quick thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "all I know is we cannot use SES and the client is set up for high volume smtp with Amazon" - this statement doesn't make sense to me

Comment: What is your SES messages per minute provisioned at.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I can see how my statement doesn't make sense. I meant that the client is already setup for high volume smtp ON Amazon (via their own servers) -- nothing runs thru SES and the plan is to keep using their own servers.